# How to scroll and load a hidden id at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem goes like this.
I have a tab on the left side and the content for each tab shows in the right side.the tab extends long way down so I should use page scroll to get bat to the top in order or the content to be viewed but I cant scroll and load the same time.

So whats happening is I need to double click the tab to load and scroll to the id to the top.can someone help me with this?

[image: BsvSI]

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could wrap the tabs in an anchor tag with href: `<a href="#content"></a>` and wrap the content in a div tag with the id `<div id="content"></div>`, this way, when you click on the tab it will redirect you to the content div without having to scroll yourself.